# jquery - sortable - changing connectWith parameter while sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

So what I want to do is something like this.

I have 3 columns now that have items inside. And if I call sortable on them I can easly sort them from one column to another. Items can have different sizes.

What I would like to do now is that when user drags item to the right most part of column 3 new column is shown (column 4).

Now creating column, making it sortable and connected with other columns is not a problem. And everything works if I have at least 1 item already inside that column. But if there is 0 items in newly created column I can't manage to put items inside of him (placeholder is shown in column 3 all the time, even when entire item is over column 4).

Height of column is set to 100% so that shouldn't be the problem and I have set dropOnEmpty to true.

Is there some way to force sortable script too put item in this empty column?
I was thinking something like changing connectedWith parameter of sortable while sorting but it doesn't work.